# How to run java class having a relative path in it through ant

Tags: java, ant, testng

I am running a java project through build.xml using ant. There is one class which has this line:

```
FileInputStream fis =new FileInputStream("./InputFile/"+workbookName);
```

When I run through ant it throws

```
java.io.FileNotFoundException: .\InputFile\LG.xlsx (The system cannot find the path specified)
```

If I specify full path in class

```
FileInputStream fis =new FileInputStream("C//InputFi//"+workbookName);
```

then it works fine from ant

But my requirement is to keep relative path and run through ant.
Kindly let me know if there's any way

Comment: How is the ant code for "run"? Exec?

Comment: Ant code:
<target name="run">
  <testng haltonfailure="false" outputdir="${TEST_HOME}/test-output/" classpathref="PROJECT_CLASSPATH" suitename="Suite1">
   <xmlfileset dir="${TEST_HOME}/src" includes="testng.xml"/>
  </testng></target>

Comment: The `testng` task has got a `workingdir` attribute, have you tried to set that to the directory containing the file?